# Why Angular not update variable or Modal in using services but its working when I click on somewhere of page

Tags: angular, angular-material, dom-events, angular-observable

When I update my modal or variable using services then its not working or there is no error,
but when I click on somewhere on a page its working.
Please tell me the solution.

Note :[ I also provide series ]

**Code**

```
  orderDetailById:  OrderDetail[];
     loadAllOrderDetail(id) {  
         this.orderService.getOrderDetail(id).subscribe(res=>{
                this.orderDetailById = res as OrderDetail[];
                console.log(this.orderDetailById);
            });
      }
```

but when I used like this its working:

```
  orderDetailById:  Observable<OrderDetail[]>;
```

but Observable have not function like (length, every) etc etc
check the attachment first.

[image]

Also see this just 00:11 sec video. 
https://youtu.be/sCuMxsp-d4w

Comment: What change detection strategy you are using? I'm assuming this is due to OnPush.

Comment: basically when i search  with number data comes from API or i bind with list.
its working good if you noted in video but i have to click on page for update angular page.
https://youtu.be/sCuMxsp-d4w

Answer (score 0):

inject the ChangeDetectorRef in your constructor

```
constructor(
    ...
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ...
)
```

and then use it with detect changes

```
loadAllOrderDetail(id) {
    this.orderService.getOrderDetail(id).subscribe(res => {
        this.orderDetailById = res as OrderDetail[];
        console.log(this.orderDetailById);
        this.cd.detectChanges();
    });
}
```

I am pretty sure this will help you, but you need to understand why.
Maybe you changed the detection strategy

Comment: Thanks Man its working for me .
"ChangeDetectorRef" explain this term Please

Comment: for me has no sense use ChangeDetectorRef. I think that the problem is that the function loadAllOrderDetail(id) must be called in the (click) function of the search button:, not only in ngOnInit.